# MATLAB signal up conversion and transmitting over the air

Tags: matlab, usrp

I have created an OFDM signal (WLAN) in MATLAB and saved the complex valued signal in a file. I then transfer the file to USRP-B210 (Software Defined Radio) and transmit over the air. Note that in MATLAB, I do not require to up-convert the signal to IF(intermediate frequency), as it is done by the radio device itself.

The signal is received by the receiver (which down-converts) and saves the file in local disk. I then process the receive file in MATLAB. Everything works perfect, and data is decoded correctly.

Now, I want to apply a Rayleigh Channel (that has Delay-Doppler effect over multipath channel). MATLAB has built in function for that [Fading Channel](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/fading-channels.html). In such case, my signal transfer works fine with minor degradation in performance (BER). But degrades as I increase Delay-Doppler effect.

My question is, while I use the channel model, I am not doing any upconversion of the baseband signal before passing it to the channel model function. Was that necessary ? Because applying channel model on the base band sounds incorrect. In that case what other options do I have ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not super familiar with this toolbox from MATLAB, but a quick look at the help page for [comm.RayleighChannel](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.rayleighchannel-system-object.html) doesn't seem to show any inputs that are carrier frequency based.  This would imply that the channel model is carrier independent.  As such, it should be able to be applied to a complex baseband signal just as readily as to an upconverted pass-band signal.

```
rayChan = 
  comm.RayleighChannel with properties:

             SampleRate: 100000
             PathDelays: 0
       AveragePathGains: 0
     NormalizePathGains: true
    MaximumDopplerShift: 130
        DopplerSpectrum: [1x1 struct]
       ChannelFiltering: true
    PathGainsOutputPort: false
```

Comment: GrapefruitIsAwesome yes, that is true. What confuses me, if I now up-convert the signal & pass through channel model. Then while feeding to the radio device will it try to upconvert again ?

Comment: @SAM I don't know you particular workflow, but it sounds like it will.  You only want to up convert once!